# Navigator and multiple views in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am playing around with React Native and trying to build a test application. I am stuck at the Navigator part: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-navigators.html.

I understand that one can change the state of the variables (as they are doing in the tutorial, increasing the index variable). What I don't really understand is how I could render different Components based on which button is clicked in my menu. In the example, it is always "MyScene" that is rendered, but with different values. How should I do to render "MyScene2" when clicking on some button?

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969423/change-parents-state-from-a-child-and-use-it-in-another-child-react-native/39971382#39971382

Comment: I can not see that the navigator is used in that question.

Comment: @theva Maybe this will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928565/this2-props-navigator-push-is-not-a-function/39958933#39958933). Here I explain how I implemented the navigator with new screen where you can add your desired components in.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! It was an issue with the ES6 arrow function definition that confused me...